# javascript not working in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

```
<script type ="text/jscript" >
         $(function(){
             $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
                 tabHandle: '.handle1',                              //class of the element that will be your tab
                 pathToTabImage: 'images/todolist.png',          //path to the image for the tab (optionaly can be set using css)

                 imageHeight: '135px',                               //height of tab image
                 imageWidth: '40px',                               //width of tab image    
                 tabLocation: 'right',                               //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
                 speed: 300,                                        //speed of animation
                 action: 'click',                                   //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
                 topPos: '200px',                                   //position from the top
                 fixedPosition: true                               //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
             });
         });

         </script>
```

I have the above code in my master page in a web application developed in vs2010. It works fine in chrome, IE. but does not work at all in mozilla firefox. What could be causing this problem? i've enabled javascript in firefox's setting tab. Plz do help.

Thankssss.

Comment: isnt it text/javascript?

Comment: Have you received any errors or warnings in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that text/jscript is not the same as text/javascript.  You want the latter.

Comment: Thanks Boris Zbarsky. It was such a small flaw. Actually i should have reviewed it before posting. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use type="text/javascript" instead of type ="text/jscript"